# Stuck in circuit analysis

Tags: pcb

[image]

I am having the following problems understanding the above circuit:

-I understand the part where the opto-coupler activates transistor T3 acting as a relay driver. I also understand that this would activate relay RL1. But how does relay RL(a) get activated to N/O? In fact, how do any of the relays marked RL(alphabet) get activated?

-When the relay is in the N/C position, how does power from the 12V SMF battery get to the output?

-The NAND gate N1 has both inputs at the same value. When the ac mains is working, wouldn't the NAND give 0 as output where as it should actually be giving 1?

```
Note: This circuit can be found at http://bestengineeringprojects.com/electronics-projects/advance-mini-ups/ along with an explanation. I can not make sense of the explainaion, hence this post.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is not the best drawn schematic.  Apparently there is a single relay, which is shown in several parts in the schematic.  That by itself is fine.  The problem is that the coil is designated RL1, but the various switch parts just RL.  Despite the different designators, it seems that RL1 and RL are really the same relay.

At least the NO and NC options for each switch part are clearly labeled.  NO stands for "normally open", and NC for "normally closed".  The NO options are therefore open when the coil is not driven and closed when driven.  The NC options are closed when the coil is not driven and open when driven.

A NAND with both inputs tied together is just a inverter.  When the opto is activated, its output is pulled low.  The NAND gate inverts this so that its output goes high, which turns on T3 and activates the relay.

The circuit for driving the opto is suspicious at best.  Note that the diode is in series with the capacitor.  That means the capacitor will eventually charge up and no current will flow thru it in steady state.  Perhaps the relay is only intended to turn on for a short time after powerup.  However, since there is no definite way to disharge the cap, the amount of time for this to reset so that the relay will again come on at next powerup is undetermined.  For a perfect cap and diode, the capacitor would charge up once and then stay charged forever, regardless of power being turned on and off.

Comment: About the capacitor in series with the diode, note they are being driven by AC. The capacitor acts as a reactance (think of it like a resistor), helping to drive the led at a correct voltage/current.

I have a pilot "lamp" made of a LED in home to indicate mains are powering a electric water heater that works like the one in this schematics.

You can find the capacitor reactance in ohms with the formula:
x(f) = 1/(2*pi*f*C)
Where f is the AC frequency and C is the capacitance.

Comment: @rica: But the diode prevents AC from passing. The current can't go back and forth, only forth, so evenually the capacitor gets charged to the peak-peak line voltage and no current will pass thru it any more.

Comment: hmmm. You are right. On my setup I have another diode in parallel with the LED but in the opposite direction, which is not the case here. My bad.

Comment: Clears things up. Olin, Nedd, thanks for the detailed replies.

Answer (score 1):

First, this is likely a bit of a concept drawing not showing every connected part, or component part numbers, hense the not so perfect connection of the cap and diode going to the opto-coupler.  The concept being that the diode gives half wave rectification to the LED side of the opto-coupler.  The circuit has delays built in so that half wave pulses are enough to keep the circuit stable in one state.

As in the other answer the relay controls all of the other multi-throw switches. This is an example of "ganged" switches, (all being changed by a single action).  The relay's switches are all shown in the NC (normally closed) state, when the battery is supplying the AC power.

The AC output (during a power failure) receives power from the battery by the fact that the battery connects to the center winding of the main transformer and is then converted to AC by the alternate switching action of Mosfet transistors T1 and T2.  The switching action on one side of the transfomer creates a higher voltage on the output side.

When the main power is working the Nand gate gets a low, by way of the opto-coupler's transistor side being turned on. For a Nand gate any Low gives a high output, which in this case turns on T3, turns on RL1, and switches all the relay switches over to the NO (normally open) state.  In that state the battery is actually being charged.

When the main power is lost the opto-coupler turns off and the other circuits turn on (by way of the relay switches all going back to their NC side). Some of the other capacitors are being used to add small delays to the switching from normal power state to the battery power state.